# how to display images side by side one after another

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This code displaying images top to bottom.

```
<tr ng-repeat='b in Brands = (Brands | firstLetter:activeLetter)'>
    <td><img src="http://localhost/{{ b.image }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75><br><br></td>
</tr>
```

I want to display images side by side. And once screen with over move to next row. Is that possible in angularJS / ui-bootstrap way?

If not angularJS / ui-bootstrap way, then what is the best way to do that?

**EDIT**
This logic working for me

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="b in Brands = (Brands | firstLetter:activeLetter)" ng-if="$index % 12 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1" ng-repeat="idx in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]">
            <img src="http://localhost/{{ Brands[idx+$parent.$index].image }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it is showing the empty boxes if remaining images are not 12.

[image]

How to remove these empty boxes in last row and display images in center (or some way to look better).

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-1" ng-repeat='b in Brands = (Brands | firstLetter:activeLetter)'>
    <img src="http://localhost/{{ b.image }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75>
</div>`

Comment: All you need to do is wrap the images in a div and center it. Control the amount of pix in each row by the width of the div element holding all of the images.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _But it is showing the empty boxes if remaining images are not 12._?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generally do this, is to apply the CSS `float` property by specifying either `float:left;` or `float:right;` as a listed property of a class for those images.